# Terraria crashes

Tags: technical-issues, terraria

Once in a while Terraria will crash and display this error message. I can't copy the text, so I took a screenshot. Not sure what this means, I have tried reinstalling the XNA framework.

[image]

Comment: Can you think of anything specific you are doing right before it crashes? It seems like the game is trying to display something, but doesn't have everything it needs to do so.

Comment: Before the most recent crash, I had started a new world and was just digging. Every time the game has crashed, I wasn't doing anything in particular.

Comment: I'd attempt to uninstall and reinstall terraria

Comment: If you have a steam version, you can try to "Verify integrity of cache" within game properties > local files. If you have some corrupt files, steam will re-download them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. Re-installing the XNA framework did not work for me. 
Re-installing Terraria fixed the issue.